# My Time Is Wrong Depending On My Location

Tags: time

My clock is set to retrieve the time automatically from the internet, and I have my time zone set properly. However, when I am at my college campus, the time is 1 hour ahead of what it should be, but when I am home, my time is correct.

What is causing this time variation?

Comment: What timezone is it? Is it one that requires daylight saving or some workaround like that? Maybe the ubuntu time-servers may not have done that adjustment yet.

Comment: If you don't travel between time zones, just set the zone manually. At one point my phone automatically set to a Chinese time zone, and my mom's computer was in Canadian time zone,  even though we're in the US.

Comment: Is your college campus in a different time zone than your home? Has your college's network adapted to daylight saving times? Do either time zones bypass daylight savings in any way?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. My timezone is Eastern Standard Time, and @Davide Cole my home and college are in the same time zone. The college computers display the correct time, but when I use my laptop there, my clock is set an hour ahead.  I am assuming that its network has adapted to daylight savings, because their desktops all display the right time (the college does have all-in-ones that use wifi as I do on campus, but I haven't checked their clocks yet. Will do).

Comment: @SuperSleuther I will heed your advice if no other solution is given. Thanks for the suggestion.